# Asymptotic for LAD - Problem 16, p.84 Van der Vaart

Tags: regression, asymptotics, least-absolute-deviations, differentiable

From Van der Vaart's *Asymptotics Statistics*, we have the derivation of the asymptotics for the least square regression (Example 5.27). Now, the problem 16 of the same section regards the asymptotics for the least absolute deviation.

I copy and paste here the problem 16.

"In Example $5.27$, consider the asymptotic behavior of the least absolute-value estimator $\hat{\theta}$ that $\operatorname{minimizes} \sum_{i=1}^n\left|Y_i-\phi_\theta\left(X_i\right)\right|$."

I am wondering how we can extend the example 5.27 knowing that the absolute value is not differentiable?

Comment: Check https://eml.berkeley.edu/~powell/e241a_sp06/qrnotes.pdf